# Не могу записать образ Archlinux

Tags: archlinux, образ

Ставил дистрибутив Ubuntu через Unetbootin и всё прошло нормально, однако что бы таким же способом поставить Арч надо изменить файл syslinux, что у меня и не получилось, т.к. я не нашёл нужную строку. Пытался сделать через dd, но мне выдаёт ошибку, что /dev/sdb не существует или нет в нём такого каталога. K3b мне тоже не помогло, записывает на диск ничего. Win32 disk imager у меня не нашёл файл формата iso. Что я делаю не так и как установить Арч.

Comment: Arch поставляется с загрузчиком, обычного `dd` хватит. Покажите команду и полученную ошибку.

Comment: Вижу непонимание обозначения разделов устройств. Так неаккуратно с dd можно доиграться и стереть данные с жесткого диска

Comment: user@user-GA-MA770T-UD3:~$ $ dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb
$: команда не найдена
user@user-GA-MA770T-UD3:~$ dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb
dd: не удалось открыть «image.iso»: Нет такого файла или каталога
user@user-GA-MA770T-UD3:~$

Comment: Файл `image.iso` должен находиться в той же директории, в которой вы находитесь. В противном случае, параметром `if` нужно передать путь к этому файлу (абсолютный или относительный). Первая команда неверна, `$` не нужен в начале.

Comment: Устройство /dev/sdb1. На вики: Используйте именно /dev/sdx, а не /dev/sdx1

Comment: Все верно, нужно именно `/dev/sdb`. Если сомневаетесь в файле, можно воспользоваться `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: >Файл image.iso должен находиться в той же директории, в которой вы находитесь
Находится

Comment: @112 «находится» — удостоверьтесь, что он называется именно image.iso. регистр букв играет роль.

Comment: Всё получилось. Перетащил файл на диск и ubuntu сам записал образ. Всё сработало. Жаль, что я не додумался сделать так сразу и неделю ломал голову.

Comment: Добавьте это в ответ, чтобы пользователи, столкнувшиеся с подобной проблемой не ломали неделю голову.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно файл archlinux.iso перетащить на диск и ubuntu сам предложит записать образ. После чего остаётся только перезагрузиться и поменять настройки BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно записать из под Win то удобно использовать [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=ru_RU), а если из под Linux то просто набрать в терминале команду:

```
# dd bs=4M if=/путь/к/образу/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync
```

где вместо sd**x**, необходимо прописать нужный диск(не раздел, для раздела указываются дополнительно цифры), можно отыскать в выводе команды:

```
$ lsblk
```

обычно это sd**b**, sd**c** ...
С командой dd нужно действовать окуратно, если промахнутся с диском то можно запороть рабочую систему или потерять важные данные на диске с данными. В общем как всегда: 10 раз отмерь, 1 - отрежь.

Также ваша флешка перед записью должна быть предварительно размонтирована:

```
# umount /dev/sdx
```

больше информации по разным способам записи образа Арча смотри в официальной вики Арча - [USB flash installation media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)